# How to write a query in Entity Framework Core for aggregating forex candle data?

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core

I have stock data in my SQL table with Open, High, Close, Low, volume, LastTrade, and Time.

And I want to query this in 1 min, 2 min, 5 min, 15 min candle

I found this SQL query on the internet

```
select
    ts,
    min(low) as low,
    max(high) as high,
    sum(volume) as volume,
    min(open) as open,
    min(close) as close
from
    (select
         t.*,
         c.*,
         first_value(open) over (partition by t.ts order by c.posix_time asc) as open,
         first_value(open) over (partition by t.ts order by c.posix_time desc) as close
     from
         generate_series('2016-01-01'::timestamp, '2016-01-02'::timestamp, interval '5 minute' ) t(ts)
     left join 
         candles c on '1970-01-01' + c.posix_time * interval '1 second' between t.ts and t.ts + interval '5 minute'
    ) t
group by
    ts;
```

But how to write this query in Entity Framework Core?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Many classes of SQL queries are _impossible_ to represent in Linq - fortunately EF (and EFCore) do let you supply-your-own SQL for manual queries - is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: Also, consider having your SQL in a UDF so it will have an optimal query-plan, then you can just call your UDF directly from EF.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? The SQL you posted looks like it's for Postgres, it won't work on MSSQL Server.

Comment: @Dai so plan query is the only option? yes, I can do this but for convenience and learning purposes, I was looking for the possibility in EFCore.
Thanks for your response :)

Comment: FWIW, I'm confident that the query you've posted **can** be done in Linq - though I'm unsure how the `first_value(open) over (partition by t.ts order by c.posix_time asc) as open` could be ported, but I can think of a few alternatives. (Linq doesn't support CTEs or Window Functions, y'see)